# getAuthToken fails with IOException on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, accountmanager

I use code like shown below to get the auth token from the AccountManager and it works perfectly on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, my Lenovo Ideapad and my Motorola RARZ phone but fails with IOException on my Galaxy S3.

Looking around this seems to be caused by lack of networking (e.g. no wifi/3G) but the phone has Internet access, I can browse the Internet and get emails.

Any tips on the causes and fix for this issue? Since Galaxy S3 is one of the most popular android phones I cannot leave it out.

```
public class LoginActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnItemClickListener,
                                                 AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>
{
  public final static String GOOGLE_SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

  private String mToken;

  private void requestToken() {
    mAccountManager.getAuthToken(mAccount, GOOGLE_SCOPE, null, this, this, null);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
    Bundle bundle = null;

    try {
      bundle  = result.getResult();
      final Intent loginIntent = (Intent)bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
      if(loginIntent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(loginIntent, AUTH_REQ_CODE);
      } else {
        mToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
      }
    } catch ( final IOException e ) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( final AuthenticatorException ae ) {
      Log.e(TAG, ae.toString());
      ae.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( final OperationCanceledException oce ) {
      Log.e(TAG, oce.toString());
      oce.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( final Exception ex ) {
      Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

}